# Categorize wordpress tags

Tags: taxonomy, tags

I have problem about categorizing wordpress TAG, in my case for language.
for example:

**postA**: englishtag1,englishtag2,englishtag3,
chinesetag1,chinesetag2,

**postB**: englishtag2,englishtag5,englishtag4,
chinesetag1,chinesetag3,

i want to show tag cloud based on the "language":

**english tag cloud**: englishtag1,englishtag2,englishtag4,englishtag5

**Chinese tag cloud**: chinesetag1,chinesetag3,chinesetag2,chinesetag4

etc..

is it possible? how to achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally found plugin to achieve this using plugins below

1. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tag-groups/
2. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/xili-tidy-tags/ << complex one

hope help someone htat need to groups the tags, catgeory or taxonomy